# How do I translate #{get 'title' /} in a Play template?

Tags: java, templates, internationalization, playframework

I have a template (`main.html`) with `#{get 'title' /}`, and I want it translated using the `&{'title'}` tag, but obviously I can't do

```
&{ #{get 'title'/} }
```

What is the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best alternative is to set the title to the translated String. Replace:

```
#{set 'title'}My Title#{/set}
```

for

```
#{set 'title'}&{'my.title.i18n.key'}#{/set}
```

If you use the short version do:

```
#{set 'title', messages.get('my.title.i18n.key') /}
```

as `messages` is an implicit object in the templates.

Comment: I can't seem to get this working. I added home: Home to my messages file and #{set 'title', messages.get('home') /}, which is causing a Template Compilation Error.

Comment: Hang on! The first one works: #{set 'title'}&{'my.title.i18n.key'}#{/set}

Answer (score 2):

There's a few alternate ways of doing things:

- You can use [`Messages.get(key)`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.3/play/i18n/Messages.html#get%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) instead of `&{key}` (within a template you can use the implicit `messages` object, i.e. `messages.get(key)`).
- I believe you can use [`Http.Request.args.get('title')`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.3/play/mvc/Http.Request.html#args) instead of `#{get 'title' /}`. Using the implicit `request` object that would be `request.args.get('title')`.

So one way to get where you're trying to go is:

```
&{request.args.get('title')}
```

Another would be to do the localization when setting the title:

```
#{set 'title', messages.get('my title key')}
```

(The top section of [the template cheat sheet](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/cheatsheet/templates) lists the implicit objects that are available.)

Comment: Template compilation error

The template /app/views/Application/index.html does not compile : Unexpected node type: EXPR found when expecting type: LABELED_ARG at line: 8 column: 24. File: /app/views/Application/index.html